Return http status code 401 when login with invalid credentials
How would i go about changing an django application that uses allauth so that it returns 401 response when invalid login credentials are provided?
I have tried to put custom logic in a custom ModelBackend but found no way to actually modify the response status code there.
I have also tried to put custom logic in a CustomAccountAdapter.authentication_failed but same issue there i found no way to change the status code.

It doesn't look like that method (or anything that uses it) has anything to do with returning an HTTPResponse, however, the package has an account middleware that will handle a custom ImmediateHTTPResponse exception, your custom logic can create a custom response and use that exception to raise it.

@metatoaster i tried to raise a ImmediateHttpResponse in a few places but it only yielded a 500, do you have some idea where i could raise it?

If it doesn't work inside your custom authentication_failed then you might not have included allauth.account.middleware.AccountMiddleware as part of the middleware configuration for your django site, as per quickstart (and the release change notes).

I managed to change the http status code by adding the following middleware last
class Auth401Middleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)        
        if request.path == "/accounts/login/" and request.method == "POST" and not request.user.is_authenticated:
            response.status_code = 401
        return response

